# How do I enable 3 finger scrolling in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, touchpad

If I disable 3 and 4-finger gestures in Touchpad Settings, using that many fingers simply does nothing. I would like it to scroll instead so I don't have to keep fingers lifted up while scrolling. Is this possible, with or without a 3rd party extension?

Comment: having 5 fingers on a hand (usually), even with the ability to scroll with three of them you need to lift some of them  from the touchpad?

Comment: If you disabled 3-finger gestures, why should 3 finger scroll work ?

Comment: I thought it was two fingers that did scrolling, 3 fingers did minimise/maximise from what I remember...

Answer (score 0):

3- and 4-finger gestures are not for scrolling. Enabling these do not make them work for scrolling.

First, here is the MS documentation on supported gestures in Windows 10 and 11: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/touch-gestures-for-windows-a9d28305-4818-a5df-4e2b-e5590f850741

Second, the list of 3- and 4- finger gestures from that article are:

> **See all open windows:** Place three fingers on the touchpad and swipe
> them away from you.
>
> **Show the desktop:** Place three fingers on the touchpad and swipe them
> towards yourself.
>
> **Switch between open windows:** Place three fingers on the touchpad and
> swipe right or left.
>
> **Open Cortana:** Tap three fingers on the touchpad.
>
> **Open action center:** Tap four fingers on the touchpad.
>
> **Switch virtual desktops:** Place four fingers on the touchpad and swipe
> right or left.

While Windows does allow modifying the 3- and 4-finger gestures, the modifications available to not include scrolling. Scrolling is a 2-finger action on Windows. You would need to find a 3rd party utility to modify this.